# Live Video on website, conferencing

Tags: windows, video, streaming

A friend of mine, an author, wants to do on-line book readings.
We have a very simple setup and would like to stream live Video through her web site.

Her client PC runs on Windows XP, has a standard Webcam and is connected to the Internet through a DSL Line.

Her web site runs on shared hosting, PHP available, no video streaming server available but plenty of space (8GB)

Does anybody have ideas how to:

- **Transmit video live from her computer/webcam input onto a video embed on her web site** (Proprietary plugins are an option)
- **Share a video conference** conducted through any free or reasonable priced video messaging solution onto a video embed on her web site?

While a free/open source solution would be preferred, a modestly priced commercial solution would also be an option.

Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[USTREAM](http://ustream.tv) seems to be a good fit for this. It allows you to transmit live from your webcam, and they even provide you with embed codes for your website:

[image]

[Stickam](http://stickam.com) also has the ability to do live broadcasts, they also provide embed codes for your website.

Comment: That looks very nice!

Comment: This looks indeed nice. I would however prefer a solution that can work as a standalone solution (possibly, and probably, with a distribution component installed on the web server). It should be ad-free, and $1 per viewer hour, what UStream charges for pay as you go, is too much for the project in question. I will leave this question open for a few more days in the hope such a solution comes up but accept this if nothing comes up.

Comment: Ah that makes things a little more clear. I'm not sure what you mean by $1 per viewer hour... do you want to charge users? Maybe Tikilive is better for you ( http://www.tikilive.org/ ). They have a PPV option ( http://www.tikilive.org/pdf/TikiLIVE_PPV.pdf )

Comment: Sorry for the long time, I check in here rarely. No, UStream's commercial enterprise charge $1 per ad-free viewer hour in the pay-as-you-go option which is quite stiff for the small business I am searching a solution for. On our end, viewing is free and should be ad-free.

Comment: Hmm. From what I've seen so far, stickam doesn't have ads (I've embedded a live stream on a webpage and watched). They provide you with embed codes. Added it to my answer.

Comment: John T, from how it works on Stack Overflow, I figured that your question would be auto-accepted by the system (it had more than 2 upvotes at the time). But apparently, it works differently here and now the question is stuck and can't be accepted at all anymore. I'm awfully sorry. Thanks a lot for your great pointers.

Comment: Because I answered prior to the bounty being started, no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind coding your own solution a bit, the new webcam features in Silverlight 4 could probably be used to create a free solution for yourself.  It's still beta at the moment, but in the videos and demos I've seen so far looks to be very promising and could be applied for just this type of situation.

Answer (score 1):

[Ustream](http://ustream.tv/) worked really well for me.

I had to set up a live stream of a funeral at the last minute, and it took me under 20 minutes to write a webpage from scratch, drop in the [Ustream](http://ustream.tv/) embed code, and run a test from my iPad. This is the only time in my life that I've seen technology work flawlessly and effortlessly.

Use [Ustream](http://ustream.tv/).