# What is the cheapest way to set up a live video webcast?

Tags: video, webcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live Video on website, conferencing](https://superuser.com/questions/85946/live-video-on-website-conferencing)

What is the cheapest way to set up a live video webcast?

Answer (score 2):

[ustream.tv](http://www.ustream.tv), and a webcam. [Tinychat](http://tinychat.com/) also is great for ad-hoc video broadcasts. Many developers use it to discuss trending topics. "Girl Developer" [Sara Chipps](http://girldeveloper.com/) is a frequent user for her developer-discussions.

Answer (score 0):

In [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) [4.0](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4-beta/) has very good support for live steaming of the webcam. Read [this](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx) article at silverlightshow.net.